# Error 2 when i call vol from python

Tags: python

I have a `run_cmd` function which returns output from a command that i give:

```
 def run_cmd(exe):
    p = subprocess.Popen(exe, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.STDOUT)
    return p.communicate()[0]
```

I can run commands like `bcdedit /v`, `format`, `etc`, but when i call `vol C:`, like:
`run_cmd('vol C:`) i will get error:
`WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified`.
But if i run in a `cmd` command `vol c:` it's works.
So, what i'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because `subprocess.Popen` by default expects an executable or a list representing the `argv` for the called process, which in your case it will look for an executable actually called `"vol C:"` (and not an executable called `vol.exe` or similar). That is unless you specify `shell=True` (which means that the shell will be used to parse the cmdline):

```
def run_cmd(cmdline):
    p = subprocess.Popen(cmdline, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True)
    return p.communicate()[0]

run_cmd('vol C:')
```

Otherwise you have to supply the command line in list form:

```
def run_cmd(argv):
    p = subprocess.Popen(argv, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.STDOUT)
    return p.communicate()[0]

run_cmd(['vol', 'C:'])
```

Comment: Thanks for explication!

Answer (score 0):

Please do the small modification.

```
import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen("vol c:", stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True)
print p.communicate()[0]
```

Ouput

```
C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop>python chk.py
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 2A3D-7B34
```

Comment: what small modification? Dumping code with no explanation is not very useful.